# Translate URL in yii

Tags: url, yii, translate

In my Yii web application, I want to translate URL in to french language. Web pages are translated but URL not. Is it possible? How can I translate. Please help me.

Comment: Which url any how you want to convert .

Comment: in url like createUrl('home/index'); , I want to translate home and index in to french language. Like wise translate all url.